# NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE - Different language (FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: azure-service-fabric, certificate-store

What could be the reason for the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE doesn't  appear to me in english ? 
I was having some issues while running some powershell scripts that was searching by the english name. I was only able to find out by the sid. I'm having some problems installing some certificates and I believe that is the reason.

$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ("S-1-5-20")
$objSID

$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objUser.Value

this returns to me NT AUTHORITY\Serviço de rede (network service in Portuguese)

How can I change that to English ?
Thanks in advance,

Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NETWORK_SERVICE account name is [localized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account?redirectedfrom=MSDN) using OS settings. You can change it by changing Windows to use English localization settings.

This account is not recognized by the security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the `LookupAccountName` function.

Your solution, lookup by SID, is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @LoekD, I had also thought about it  but given that I had some in English and some in Portuguese, I imagine could be something else. I imagine that there is no way to change the description ? in the registry perhaps.. ?